# Auto-incrementing from 0 in Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, auto-increment

I needed an id field in my rails migration that auto-increments from 0 and not 1.Any idea?
Thanks & Cheers !

Comment: just curious why you need that?

Comment: @Shreyas do you mean SQL auto increment from 0 or do you mean filenameing from 000_create_sth.rb ?

Comment: I mean auto-incrementing the id field from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in mysql Advance option "The initial AUTO_INCREMENT" value for the Table.
you can set there but **i don't know whether you can set that using Rails Migration or not**.

Comment: Could you please paste the SQL query here?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your db/migrate-file:

```
create_table :table_name, :options => "auto_increment = 0" do |t|
  ...
end
```